# Reversed Positional Parameters

Tags: powershell, command-line-arguments

I'd like to use positional parameters for a PowerShell script I'm writing, but I want the parameters to be entered from right to left (with one being mandatory and one named). Here's an example of what it'd look like:

```
command [-namedParams andTheirValues] [[param3] param2] param1
```

Or for each use case separately:

```
command [-namedParams andTheirValues] param1
command [-namedParams andTheirValues] param2 param1
command [-namedParam andItsValue] param3 param2 param1
```

I attempted to use `[parameter(Position=n)]` with negative indexes (since what I really want is to bind parameters based on their position to the end) but that didn't work:

```
param (
    [String]$namedParam,
    [parameter(Position=-3)][String]$param3,
    [parameter(Position=-2)][String]$param2,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=-1)][String]$param1
)
```

Any ideas? If I need to I'll just process the arguments in code, but I'm hoping for syntactical sugar to do this for me.

Comment: You might not be able to do this with advanced functions in how they are designed. You would need to play with `$args` possibly. You are trying to do backwards what PowerShell was designed to do.

Comment: FWIW I think this is a good question just potentially unrealistic. I take it back. I think there is a way to do this

Comment: It might just make more sense for me to make all three arguments required, but I'm pretty sure I've seen examples with positional parameters being reversed with built-in PowerShell commandlets. If I find any then I'll use that as my example instead and it'll resolve any concerns of whether this is a realistic question.

Comment: I just finished an answer that I think covers this in the way that you wanted with a little extra coding. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question......As you have discovered you cannot use negative values for defining positional arguments. Closest I found for a reference for this was from [about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx):

> The value of the Position argument is specified as an integer. A position
>           value of 0 represents the first position in the command, a position 
>           value of 1 represents the second position in the command, and so on.

That would be the best support for the lack of negative values. Documentation could be wrong but as you experimented it does not work.

However, I think I figured out an easy way to deal with this. Consider the following function which contains both named and "positional"ish parameters. We use the [advanced function parameter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx) `ValueFromRemainingArguments`. Note that I used quotes several times in this answer around "positional" since they are not true positional parameters.

```
function Das-Bagel{
    param (
        [String]$namedParam,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                      ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
        [String[]]$remainingArguments
    )

    $param1 = $remainingArguments[-1]
    $param2 = $remainingArguments[-2]
    $param3 = $remainingArguments[-3]

    Get-Variable -Name param* | select name, value
}
```

All it will do is display the param# variables and their values. That being said lets look at the output from these 2 different commands. First with only the one "positional" parameter.

```
PS C:\Users\Cameron> Das-Bagel -namedParam This First 

Name   Value
----   -----
param1 First
param2      
param3
```

Now we run with 3 "positional" parameters

```
PS C:\Users\Cameron> Das-Bagel -namedParam This First Second Third 

Name   Value 
----   ----- 
param1 Third 
param2 Second
param3 First
```

The first has only the one other parameter beyond the named therefore it goes in the first position. In the second example it becomes the third parameter. Parameters not present will show as nulls for their respective variables. PowerShell is nice in that way in that it will not cause an error (be default). You would need to account for that possibility in your code but I imagine you have that covered.

Also since we made it mandatory the function call would fail if we omitted the "positional" parameters.

Comment: By the way, this solution was used to support the following parameter options: `./script.ps1 [-Option1 | -Option2] [[user] server | user@server] file`